# Usage of the abbreviations "w/" and "w/o" in presentations

Tags: abbreviations

I like to use the abbreviations "w/" for "with" and "w/o" for "without" on my powerpoint slides and also in emails. According to this discussion [Are "w/o", "w/", "b/c" common abbreviations in the US?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115367/are-w-o-w-b-c-common-abbreviations) the meaning of these abbreviations is well known in English speaking countries.

Recently, a colleague pointed out that these abbreviations do not look very professional on slides presented at some conferences. Since we are both non-native speaker, I'd like to know your opinion on using them on slides, does that look awkward or non-professional to native-speakers?

(I am working in natural sciences, if this matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native English speaker, those abbreviations seem  inappropriate for use on a Powerpoint presentation. Mostly, it just looks lazy and sloppy. I tend to leave abbreviations such as the ones you have mentioned for instances that require shorthand, such as personal notes and emails.

Comment: Correct. Also, usage of words is a sign of a poor PowerPoint presentation.